# Water dipole by symmetry argument

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, dipole-moment

I'm a mathematician and I'm studying Group and Representation theory and I came across with an interesting exercise involving physics, although I don't know physics, since I'm a mathematician, I found the problem very interesting and would be glad if you could help me solve and understand the problem.

So, the problem is: (point group $C_{4\sigma_{v}}$) using symmetry arguments show what is the direction of the dipole momentum vector for the Water Molecule.